# awk to sum values among grouped lines after specific str match and header

Tags: regex, string, awk, count

I' ve this program in awk:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[>;]"
  OFS=";"
}

function p(a, i)
{
   for(i in a)
     print ">" i, "*nr=" ln

}
/^>/ {p(out);ln=0;split("",out);next}
/[*]/  {idx=$2 OFS $3; out[idx]}
{ln++}
END {
  if (ln) p(out)
}
```

it works on a file like this:

```
>Cluster 300
0   151nt, >last238708;size=1... *
>Cluster 301
0   141nt, >last103379;size=1... at -/99.29%
1   151nt, >last104482;size=1... *
>Cluster 302
0   151nt, >last104505;size=1... *
>Cluster 303
0   119nt, >last325860;size=1... at +/99.16%
1   122nt, >last106751;size=1... at +/99.18%
2   151nt, >last284418;size=1... *
3   113nt, >last8067;size=3... at -/100.00%
4   122nt, >last8102;size=3... at -/100.00%
5   135nt, >last14200;size=2... at +/99.26%
>Cluster 304
0   151nt, >last285146;size=1... *
```

What I need is that the program print, for each cluster, the id (lastxxxxxx) of the line with the asterisk and that computes the sum of all the "size=" numbers . for example for Cluster 303 it has to output this:

`>last284418;nr=11`
and for Cluster 304:
`>last285146;nr=1`
for the moment my code is only able to count the lines and sum them but doesn't take into account the "size=" value.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
/^>Cluster [0-9]+/{
  if(sum){
    print clus_line ORS val_line" = "sum
  }
  val_line=sum=clus_line=""
  clus_line=$0
  next
}
{
  match($0,/size=[0-9]+/)
  line=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*size=/,"",line)
  sum+=line
}
/\*$/{
  match($0,/>last[^;]*/)
  val_line=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}
END{
  if(sum){
    print clus_line ORS val_line" = "sum
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                          ##Starting awk program from here.
/^>Cluster [0-9]+/{                            ##Checking condition if line starts from Cluster with digits in line then do following.
  if(sum){                                     ##Checking if variable sum is NOT NULL then do following.
    print clus_line ORS val_line" = "sum       ##Printing values of clus_line ORS(new line) val_line space = space and sum here. 
  }
  val_line=sum=clus_line=""                    ##Nullifying val_line, sum and clus_line here.
  clus_line=$0                                 ##Assigning current line to clus_line here.
  next                                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  match($0,/size=[0-9]+/)                      ##Using match function to match size= digits in line.
  line=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)               ##Creating line which has sub-string for current line starts from RSTART till RLENGTH.
  sub(/.*size=/,"",line)                       ##Substituting everything till size= keyword here with NULL in line variable.
  sum+=line                                    ##Keep on adding value of digits in line variable in sum here.
}
/\*$/{                                         ##Checking condition if a line ends with * then do following.
  match($0,/>last[^;]*/)                       ##Using match function to match >last till semi-colon comes here.
  val_line=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)       ##Creating val_line which has sub-string of current line from RSTART+1 till RLENGTH-1 here.
}
END{                                           ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  if(sum){                                     ##Checking if variable sum is NOT NULL then do following.
    print clus_line ORS val_line" = "sum       ##Printing values of clus_line ORS(new line) val_line space = space and sum here.
  }
}'  Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```